# OpenERP Developer Mode modification

Tags: python, xml, odoo

If we do some modification to our form views in Openerp 7 Developer mode (Ex : add onchange function and when it called some fields goes invisible)
is this modification automatically added to relevant view.xml files ?

I done such a thing.but my account_view.xml file not updated.but in database side ir_ui_view table saved with that record.please advice me to find that where is my missing point.?

**EDITED :** 
actually my account_view.xml cannot change.but when i'm change some changes to other view.xml files, they shows result when i restart the server & upgrade the modules.
but only when i change this account_view.xml file its not gives a result.but when i do some changes to account view through "Developer mode" they affected.
help me to seek what is the issue with that ?
(seems not using my account_view.xml) i tried to some simple changes also like menu item text change.they also not affected.but when i do for other module's view.xml they affected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That changes will not affect any xml file. Changes done directly from web-client will last until you update related module, those changes are not permanent.

For permanent changes you have to change in xml file and update that module.

Comment: then both are conflict.?my issue only with account_view.xml file

Comment: Not at all. Those changes will not conflict.

Comment: then why only account_view.xml files not affected when i changed ?

Comment: ok got it.issue with my old db.i migrate to fresh db
now issue sorted  :-)